# Logic of implementing a progress or loading frame/monitor in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, progress-bar, loading

I have a program that collects data via HTTP calls, then sort's the data and uses it in various ways. I then have a basic GUI to display my findings. Due to the 15 second interval that must be between calls to the server it takes around 3 minutes before my GUI pops up. My code in the main in simplified form is:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    getData();
    sortData();
    playWithData();
    startUI(DataClass theData);

}
```

What I would like to do is have a pop up window that happens at the beginning of my program and then finishes just before my main UI starts. What is the basic logic and best practices to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Show the window as a standard Swing frame with the progress bar on it.

Start your process running in a SwingWorker.

In the update methods from the SwingWorker update the status of the progress bar.

Once the process completes either launch a new frame and close the progress one or swap the panel out on the progress one and turn that into the new main window.